# Mandatory(*) symbol is not showing for the Muslti Select Control in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I Wanted make the Multiselect Dropdown to be mandatory field,i have used the PXDefault() Attribute at Dac level,it is throwing validation but the Madatory symbol is not displaying in the UI.

```
    [PXDBString(250, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Mapped Warehoueses",Required =true)]
    [PXDefault()]
    [KNFNWarehousePrefetch()]
    public virtual string MappedWarehoueses { get; set; }
    public abstract class mappedWarehoueses : IBqlField { }
```

Answer (score 0):

When that happens, you can add the asterisk symbol using the RowSelected Event:

Here is a field without the asterisk:
[image]

This it the DAC Definition:

```
[PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Nickname")]
```

Then, the RowSelected event is defined:

```
protected virtual void [DACName]_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired<[DACName].nickname>(sender, true);
```

After that, the asterisk is visible in the UI:
[image]

**Note** that the field does not become mandatory. Only the symbol was added in the UI.

Comment: @Praveen-Pola  I am reviewing the Stackoverflow answers. Were you able to test this?

Comment: I tested this in a tab element and it did not work. I believe tab elements are able to have required asterisks by them, are they not? I noticed that fields I marked as PXDefault in a tab area also not showing the asterisk, so I'm not sure what's going on there.